# Android - Alertdialog for authenticated firebase user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-alertdialog

I want to display an alertdialog when the user logs in for the first time (I am using firebase authentication). Any ideas on how I can do that? I tried using SharedPreferences but that just displays the alertdialog the first time the application runs on the device. I want it to be user specific, so that the alertdialog is displayed for every user the first time they login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to show the dialog just before you call finish() on your login activity. Another way is to check that FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() doesn't return null and then display the dialog from the activity you're calling it from right now. After this you store a "alert displayed"-flag in the preferences associated with the user id and also check for the presence of this before displaying the alert.

I'm sorry for not being more specific. Please post your code if you want a more precise answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your second solution

Answer (score 1):

In your `onActivityResult` you can show the `progressDialog` like this.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.setMessage("Connecting Please Wait!..");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setIndeterminate(false);
            progress.show();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

and the `firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account)` function is

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        progress.cancel();
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information 
//and here you can use your sharedPreference for that Account.
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

and the following code is where you can check for the whether the user is signedIn or not

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };
```

I hope it helps.
As you see `FirebaseAuth` tends to help you login without `sharedPreference` but if you want to use it you can just make sure you destroy `sharedPreference` on the click of SignOut button in your Application